# Ionic app REST API call pointing to a wrong URL

Tags: android, cordova

I have been experiencing this issue since I tried run my app in a device..
I re-install the cordova-whitelist plugin.

When I try  to run the app again from the browser using `ionic serve` command.
the app calls to the wrong API..

below is the log in my console when I try to login to the app.

`POST http://192.168.43.57:8100/auth/login 404 (Not Found)`

the `$http` url declared on my JS code is different from what the console is pointing to.

**login controller**

```
$scope.login = function() {
        var credentials = {
            username: $scope.loginData.username,
            password: $scope.loginData.password
        }
        $auth.login(credentials).then(function() {

            $http.get('http://api.mydomain.com/api/login')
            .success(function(response){

                var user = JSON.stringify(response.user);

                localStorage.setItem('user', user);

                $rootScope.currentUser = response.user;

                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                  disableBack: true
                });
                $state.go('tabs.download');
            })
            .error(function(){
                var alertPopUp = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Login Failed!',
                    template: 'Invalid credentials'
                });
            })
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.ticappnew343084" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"  xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>Test Mobile</name>
<description>
    TIC Inspection Report Generator
</description>
<author email="user@example.com" href="http://example.com/">
  Author Name
</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
</feature>
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.43.57:8100"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please show me your config.xml

Answer (score 0):

after reading all my codes I finally found the solution..
it seems that I have forgot to specify the login api url to my app config..

so I added this line of code in my `app.js` file

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider){
       $authProvider.loginUrl = 'http://api.mydomain.com/api/login'
})
```

then changed the url in my login function from

`$http.get('http://api.mydomain.com/api/login')`

to 
`$http.get('http://api.mydomain.com/api/user')`

this api retrieves the user information from the server..